# Repairing a Crimped Titanium Frame

Tags: damage, titanium

I have a Van Nicholas Astraeus Titanium bike, and recently had problems with removing the seatpost. The aluminium shim oxidised itself to my frame. I took it to the bike shop, and in our efforts they crimped the top tube when clamping it into the bike stand, as put it in super tight as we were going to try and hammer the seatpost out.

I'm rather upset at my once beautiful bike is now tarnished. Do I have any hope of fixing this? Would painting the whole frame, and using filler on these 'dents' work?  Can't actually believe I'm writing this, absolutely gutted.

[image: Crimped top tube]

Comment: What is the bike shop's position on paying to replace it? It seems to me that you shouldn't have to figure this out, that they'd be the ones on the hook...

Comment: Having just looked at the list price on just the frame, I'd insist that the shop either replace it or pay to have it sent back the manufacturer for repairs.

Comment: I dunno, I was helping the mechanic as well. I don't what to do.

Comment: If they were the ones in charge of clamping your bike up, it should be them trying to figure out how to fix it. It would one thing if it were a cheapo bike, but something like this needs to be repaired professionally. I'm sure it was an accident, but they have insurance to cover themselves when the screw up.

Comment: Thanks, I'm due to fly out to Challenge Roth (Germany), I'll take photos, get advice.

Comment: Before my flight and bike packing.

Comment: I'd contact Van Nicholas to get their advice. Some manufacturers are really good about offering repair services, others not so much.

Comment: It's probably just cosmetic. Just Ride it. If the dent gets bigger, then worry about repair. Otherwise I'd ignore it.

Comment: You could get a sheet metal shop to bend up a piece of thin stainless to cover the area.  Glue it on.  It would be a bit tricky to get a good smooth fit, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not worried about cosmetics, these dents won't affect the frame at all.

I had a massive dent on top tube of my Ti trials bike from bad crash. And rode the bike for years after that. And nothing happened to the frame. Titanium is very good in for this. Dents won't affect the overall lifespan.

Comment: Yeah, the dents are where they are least likely to cause any structural problem.  And the reason they are there is because the tubing is very thin in that area, because strength is not needed there.